# How to add a julian day to a date in a loop?

Tags: linux, date

I am trying to loop through two kind of dates a %Y%m%d and a %Y%j (julian day)

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

for d in {0..24};
        do day=$(date -d "20120207 +${d}days" +%Y-%m-%d); echo $day;
                startday=$(date -d "2012038 +${d}" +%Y%j); echo $startday;

done
```

However when I run it i get this error:

```
2012-02-07
date: invalid date `2012038 +0'
```

I don't know what is wrong whit it, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date` command doesn't accept a Julian date for the `-d` parameter.  Would something like this work instead?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

startdate="20120207"

for d in {0..24}; do
    day=$(date -d "${startdate} + ${d} days" +%Y-%m-%d);
    echo $day;

    startday=$(date -d "${startdate} + ${d} days" +%Y%j);
    echo $startday;
done
```

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly!! :) , I see know the problem is trying to set the date as a Julian day itself. Thank you!